# Describing entities in a database

Tags: php, database, entity-framework, database-design

Im doing a module on php now database design has never been easy for me, the one question I am working on **is very vague and confusing**, I am hoping someone can possibly provide me with some clarity by skimming over my answer.

### Question Reads As Follow:

[image]

**Describe the entities:** *(4-marks)*

That's it the above is all they are asking for, now there are a few things which make me doubt my answer, namely:

There are 8 tables but 4 marks are awarded, thus are their 8 or 4 entities, considering the table is not normalized.

My answer to the above question is the following:

```
<p>The Entities for the data model include <i><b>the following tables</b></i>:
<ul>
<li>Actors</li>
<li>Producers</li>
<li>Film Certificate</li>
<li>Genres</li>
</ul>
```

Is this just an incredibly easy question, or am I missing something?

Comment: The main entity seem to be tblFilmTitles, I'd probably write quite a bit about the different tables (some entity, some join tables). Im not convinced 4 marks for the answer means "list 4 table names". It also made me remember to appreciate sensible naming, that is some extremely verbose naming

Comment: Thanks @JimL appreciate, thumbs up for the naming remark

Comment: The key is the word [entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity) here. Which of the tables represent entities? The rest is only association or typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the entity-relationship model, the following elements of your schema are entities:

- Actors
- Producers
- RoleTypes
- FilmGenres
- FilmTitles
- FilmCertificates
- FilmsActorRoles

And the explicit relationships are:

- FilmsActorRoles
- FilmTitleProducers

Technically the FilmTitles table includes two additional relationships:

- Between FilmTitles and FilmGenres
- Between FilmTitles and FilmCertificates

An entity-relationship diagram in Chen's original notation makes it much clearer how to interpret the model.  I left out the Hungarian data type prefixes since I don't consider them relevant in a conceptual model.

[image: A proper entity-relationship diagram]

FilmsActorRoles is an interesting table.  It's both a relationship (since its key contains the keys of other entities) and an entity (since its key contains a local attribute), thus I drew it as a weak associative entity.  It allows Actors to play multiple characters of the same type in a single movie, as long as they have different names.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee: I believe you want an answer based on the entity-relationship model rather than Entity Framework.  The latter is a Microsoft .NET object-relational mapper and unlikely to be included in a module on PHP.  If not, I'll adjust or remove my answer according to your feedback.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you for your effort really appreciate it mate

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand what *marks* mean, but I think adding a `Roles` table to your current schema may be the answer. Because it has something to do with both Actor and Film, so we can't embed it into any of the former tables.

Comment: Usually means the same as points, so answering this question is rewarded with 0-4 points